# Symfony2 assets not working after web folder rename

Tags: php, css, symfony, assets

First of all, I've changed my web directory to public_html using the instructions on the [symfony cookbook website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory)

My CSS file were working before but not anymore.

When I dump the assets using the command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

The CSS files generated are empty.

The CSS files are also not being echoded in the html.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Noquox I did `read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../../public_html"` as noted in the documentation.

Comment: try to define in `config.yml` something like this:

`framework:

#other params...

    templating:

        engines: ['twig']

        assets_base_urls: http://yourdomain.com/public_html/`

Comment: @Noquox just tried, no success :(

Comment: @Noquox cleared cache, did the following in config.yml - `templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_base_urls:
            http: ["http://richie.local/PWD/public_html"]`

Comment: @Noquox doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

try passing directory to `assetic:dump` command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump public_html --env=prod --no-debug
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using symfony 2+

```
php app/console assets:install /username/public_html
```

or if you're working locally you can do something like this

```
php app/console assets:install C:/xampp/htdocs/dev_symfony_project/public_html
```